# Resistors lose resistance after a while

Tags: resistors, surface-mount, watts, failure

I have 3 different batch of resistors (10k 0805 SMD) which all fail the same way. I am supplying 5V across the resistor, with an ammeter connected in series.  For the first hour or so everything go as expected (current is 5V/10k=0.5mA) after that the current start to increase fluctuating, and if I cut the power and measure the resistor, it has less resistance.

For the specific setup I thought that 0805 resistors are 1/10W so I thought it was ok (0.0005*5=0.0025W.)

What is the problem here? Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: It would be cool if you post a before and an after pic of your set up. From your description, everything seems Kosher.

Comment: What is the exact part number of the resistor? I mean, like a manufacturer P/N, or DigiKey, Mouser, ELFA/Distrelec, Jameco, etc. distributor stock number?

Comment: Do you use no-clean water-soluble flux to solder your resistors?

Comment: The flux I am using is Weller brand, so I guess I am ok with that, and I haven't got any P/N as these resistors were bought on eBay.
Right now I am running a test without using any paste at all, so I'll see after a few hours ...